# Displaying Checkboxes in mvc3 razor

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am creating Mvc 3 razor databasefirst application. For this I have Tblskills table and TblEmployeeDetails. I want to display skills in checkboxes from database in create page for this.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Create() {            
    List<TblSkill> Skills =   EmployeeMVC.Infrastructure.HtmlHelpers.GetTblSkill().ToList();
    ViewBag.skill = new List<TblSkill>(HtmlHelpers.GetTblSkill());
    return View();
}
```

**Create View**

```
@{
       List<EmployeeMVC.Models.TblSkill> Skills = ViewBag.skill;
       for (int i = 0; i < Skills.Count; i++)
       {
           Response.Write("<td style='border: none;'>");
           Response.Write(string.Format("<input type='checkbox' id='skill{0}' name='skill'      value='{0}' {2}/><label for='skill{0}'>{1}</label><br/>",
           Skills[i].SkillsId, "&nbsp;" + Skills[i].Skills + "&nbsp;",
           (EmployeeMVC.Infrastructure.HtmlHelpers.GetTblSkill())
            ));
           Response.Write("</td>");
           if ((i + 1) % 3 == 0)
           {
               Response.Write("</tr><tr>");
           }
       }
                    }
```

**and in GetTblSkill method**

```
 public static  IQueryable<TblSkill> GetTblSkill()
        {

            return (from x in db.TblSkills
                    select x);
        }
```

I am not getting checkboxes in the 
Skills field those r displaying in starting page

Comment: why oh why oh why are you using `response.write`????!! You are completly missing the point of Razor. use `@Html.CheckBoxFor`

Comment: Also the line of code `List<EmployeeMVC.Models.TblSkill> Skills = ViewBag.skill;` is pointless. I think you need to read more about MVC as your view code is bad.

Comment: if I used @Html.CheckBoxFor ,i am getting only one checkbox so instead of that I used List

Comment: you have to use @Html.CheckBoxFor for every skills you want to edit properties

Comment: Read this article...http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx